# Zip files into weekly archive with week number

Tags: server, backup, find, zip

I am trying to take a weekly archive of a folder to separate zip files.

```
find . -name '*.txt' -ctime +7 -exec zip "archive-$("date+%Y-%U").zip" {} \;
```

I am stuck on how to name the zip file. Any alternate way to do this would also be welcome. (like better compression using 7z or something else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be enough for your case:

```
 find . -name '*.txt' -ctime +7 | zip archive-$(date +%Y%U).zip -@
```

---

**example:**

```
find . -name '*.txt' -ctime +7 | zip archive-$(date +%Y%U).zip -@
```

output:

```
  adding: a.txt (stored 0%)
  adding: b.txt (stored 0%)
```

Now to make sure of naming:

```
 ls
```

output is:

```
archive-201525.zip  a.txt  b.txt  c
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I was not able to try it out until today. I'm getting a message "zip error: Nothing to do! (archive-201528.zip)".

Comment: Figured out the problem. ctime +7. the files were created within last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

First date has a format of YYYYMMDD, which is how I name my backups. Second example is week number (%U) with leading zero like you asked. Oops, gotta escape those backquotes.

`` #!/bin/bash
# Do 'man strftime' for more date format options.
mydate=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
basedir=/home/username/backups
zipfile=$basedir/backup-$mydate.zip
echo File name is $zipfile
# Now get week number with %U.
mydate=`date +"%U"`
echo Mydate with week number is $mydate
zipfile=$basedir/backup-$mydate.zip
echo Zipfile is $zipfile ``

Answer (score -1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
   Case (find) in
     name="true"
     name="(name.zip)"
     find . -name '*.txt' -ctime +7 'name=("name of the file")' -exec zip "archive-$("date+%Y-%U").zip" {} \;
   endl
```

and it might work fine this way.