# Ideal way to take zip backup

Tags: command-line, find, zip

I am trying to zip text, csv files from a folder on a weekly basis. Based on answer given to my [earlier question,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639440/zip-files-into-weekly-archive-with-week-number) I got this code working.

`sudo find . -mtime +7 | sudo zip -m archive-$(date +%Y-W-%U).zip -@`

I would like to fine tune this a bit more so that:

- Files with certain strings are excluded.
- zip output is saved to a different location

I thought I got the first part with the below command, but it keeps freezing up.

`sudo find . -mtime +7 | sudo zip -m -x /*excludestring1* /*excludestring2* archive-$(date +%Y-W-%U).zip -@`

I am not able to figure out a way to save it to a different location. I could include "*.zip" as an exclusion, but I would prefer to save it to a different location. Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. To exclude some patterns, use the `-x` option at the end and use single quotes around the patterns so that the patterns are expanded by `zip` not by shell :

   ```
   sudo find . -mtime +7 | sudo zip -m  archive-$(date +%Y-W-%U).zip -@ -x '/*excludestring1*' '/*excludestring2*'
   ```
2. To save the zip file to a different location, use the absolute path (or relative path) to the location you want to save the `zip` file :

   ```
   sudo find . -mtime +7 | sudo zip -m -x /*excludestring1* /*excludestring2* /where/to/save/archive-$(date +%Y-W-%U).zip -@
   ```

   Replace `/where/to/save` with the actual path where you want to save the zip file.

   For example, to save it in `/tmp/spam/` directory :

   ```
   sudo find . -mtime +7 | sudo zip -m -x /*excludestring1* /*excludestring2* /tmp/spam/archive-$(date +%Y-W-%U).zip -@
   ```

Comment: I think it is working. But I have about 22000 files in that directory that it just hangs after a bit of time. I have removed all the files and will try it.

I am thinking about putting it in crontab to run everyday with mtime as -1, so all the fresh file will be added to the current week zip files every day. Will that work?

Comment: @SunilJ It needs some manipulation as you can imagine so would take some time....

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zip/) states that the `\` should be used to avoid shell filename substitution, and let `zip` expand the wildcards itself.

Alternatively you can use the `-x` switch to specify a file listing any exclusions in the format `-x@excludes.lst`

On a slightly different tack, the `find` command has `-not` and `-path` options which can be used for similar effect.